# MVC Web Application Bundles and Script, Style Rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application and I have this **Bundle Config**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        }
    }
}
```

This is one of my **view page**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
      <title></title>
<script>
 <-- This?? -->
</script>
```

how can i render the bundles? I am using Asp.net Web Application using asp.net aspx view

Answer (score 3):

You use for MVC:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/WebFormsJs")
```

And for WebForms:

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/WebFormsJs") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can check like this.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/WebFormsJs")  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs")  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick
Make sure `Microsoft ASP.Net Web Optimization` Framework is installed your project.

```
 <script src="<%=BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryui")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jquery")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i am receiving error  The name 'BundleTable' does not exist in the current context same wih the script.render 'Script' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I have installed the nuget `Microsoft ASP.Net Web Optimization already`

Comment: @JohnPaulCirilos use <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %> on your page

Comment: i got it, configured my web.config